# Zend_File_Transfer: Rename file after upload

Tags: zend-framework, upload, rename

I'm trying to rename the uploaded file with the rename-addFilter. The actual upload already works, but the files are just uploaded and not renamed, so how can I do this? 
Here's my Controller-Code, that uploads the file:

```
        //Getting the new filename, works perfectly:
        $name = explode('.', $form['pic']);
        $ext = $name[1];
        $mapper = new Application_Model_CmsMap();
        $row = $mapper->fetchRow('childId = "' . $id . '" AND type= "pic"');
        $new_filename = $row->name.'.'.$ext;

        //All images will and are be stored in /public/images/
        //Maybe the picture should be replaced, so it should be overwrited, in case it already exists
        $upload->addFilter('Rename', array(
            'target' => '/images/'.$new_filename,
            'overwrite' => true,
            )
        );

        $upload->receive();
```

Comment: I think you might be receiving the file before you are applying the filter. If you are calling getValues() against the form it will recieve the file. **from reference:** _Per default the file will automatically be received when you call getValues() on the form. The reason behind this behaviour is, that the file itself is the value of the file element._ **So:** _Still, sometimes you may want to call getValues() without receiving the file. You can archive this by calling setValueDisabled(true). To get the actual value of this flag you can call isValueDisabled()._ I hope this helps...

Comment: I think, this will help me in the future. 
Unfortunately, I need the data of the form, because I use one controller for multiple edits. The attribute 'type' of this forms call the needed actions to add or update the database or in this case, a file.
But as you see in my own answer: PHP is quite simple and works perfectly. So why care?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Screw Zend.
Good ol' PHP is easy and works perfectly:

```
rename('images/'.$form['pic'], 'images/'.$new_filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

Should work :-)

```
    $transferAdapter = new Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http();
    $transferAdapter->receive();

    $newFilename = 'MY_NEW_FILE';

    $filterFileRename = new Zend_Filter_File_Rename(array(
        'target'    => 'PATH' + $newFilename,
    ));

    $file = $transferAdapter->getFileName();

    // new location and name..
    $movedFile = $filterFileRename->filter($file);
```